# Select file via JFileChooser and then send via HTTP request

Tags: java, file, http, jfilechooser

The title pretty much sums up everything. I have a JFileChooser instance which lets me choose a file. I want to send the selected file to a web service via HTTP.

The problem is I don't know how to get access to the contents of the selected file (which is an image) and then serialize it in a form (maybe base64 encoding) and then send it via HTTP.

So the sending is not the problem here, I know how to initiate a HTTP request. It's just that I don't have anything to send - I don't know how to make use of the selection of the JFileChooser.

This is the method that selects the file:

```
private JFileChooser fc;
...
public void fileSelect() {
    if (fc == null) {
        fc = new JFileChooser();
        fc.addChoosableFileFilter(new ImageFilter());
        fc.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
        fc.setFileView(new ImageFileView());
        fc.setAccessory(new ImagePreview(fc));
    }

    int returnVal = fc.showDialog(null, "Attach");

    File selectedFile = null;
    if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        selectedFile = fc.getSelectedFile();
    }

    fc.setSelectedFile(null);
}
```

How do I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

Use this byte array to send it to your WebService.

```
final byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(selectedFile.getAbsolutePath()));
```